# Can't use SFINAE, type traits and static_assert in MSVC10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, visual-c++, static-assert

I've been investigating the use of some judicious static assertions to improve error messages. Here's an example:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T> struct is_less_than_comparable {
    template<typename Test> static char test(decltype(*static_cast<Test*>(nullptr) < *static_cast<Test*>(nullptr)));
    template<typename Test> static int test(...);
    static const bool value = std::is_same<char, decltype(test<T>(true))>::value;
};
template<typename K, typename V> class map {
public:
    static_assert(is_less_than_comparable<K>::value, "Key type must be less-than comparable!");
};
struct x {};
int main() {
    map<x, int> intmap;
}
```

IDEONE will happily reject this code with the nice, clean error message I was hoping to get (once you replace nullptr with 0, anyway). But MSVC will not fire the static assertion and compiles this code just fine- even if I add some member functions and start calling on them.

Comment: The code isn't compiling for me.  Are some additional header files needed?

Comment: I think this is related to VC++ not performing two-phase lookup of template dependent arguments.

Comment: @BenVoigt : My impression is that VC++ 2010 is just flat out broken when trying to use `decltype` for SFINAE. I've given up on attempting to use it at all :-[

Comment: You should check out the recently added operator traits to Boost.TypeTraits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with VC++ 2010 handling of the metafunction `is_less_than_comparable`, not with `static_assert`.

If you change the code to:

```
static const bool value = std::is_same<double, decltype(test<T>(true))>::value;
```

Then it will be false regardless of which overload is picked.  The assertion then fires.

Evidently the wrong overload is being selected, SFINAE isn't removing the candidate with `char` return type.

---

Simpler test (incorrectly prints `1`):

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T> struct is_less_than_comparable {
    template<typename Test> static char test(decltype(*static_cast<Test*>(nullptr) < *static_cast<Test*>(nullptr)) b);
    template<typename Test> static int test(...);
    static const bool value = std::is_same<char, decltype(test<T>(true))>::value;
};
struct x {};
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << is_less_than_comparable<x>::value << std::endl;
}
```

---

The compiler is, for no apparent reason, <strike>providing a `bool operator<(x, x)` operator, thus</strike> generating `int is_less_than_comparable<T>::test<T>(bool)`.  If a user-defined comparison operator is provided, its return type is correctly picked up.  This operator isn't coming in with one of the headers, I can repro the `decltype` resolving to `bool` with no headers included.

This generates the proper error:

```
decltype(*(x*)nullptr < *(x*)nullptr) b;

error C2676: binary '<' : 'x' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

**I think this is related to VC++ not performing two-phase lookup of template dependent arguments.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what you're looking for in an answer here, so here's a type trait that works fine in VC++ 2010:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace supports
{
    namespace details
    {
        struct return_t { };

        template<typename T>
        static T& make();
    }

    template<typename T>
    details::return_t operator <(T const&, T const&);

    template<typename T>
    struct less_than : std::integral_constant<
        bool,
        !std::is_same<
            decltype(details::make<T>() < details::make<T>()),
            details::return_t
        >::value
    > { };
}
```